# Manually initialized embedding lead to inferior results in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

In this project[[source](https://github.com/nju-websoft/OpenEA/blob/master/dbp2.0/main.py)], I'm doing entity alignment by MTransE model. This code works fine.
I would like to save a initialized embedding, and reproducing the training process.
My method is to save(np.save) the embedding after     `tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=self.session)`,
and manually load(np.load) the embedding next time. The manually initialized embedding leads to bad training result.

The original automatic initializing code:

```
def _define_variables(self):
    with tf.variable_scope('KG' + 'embeddings'):
        self.ent_embeds = xavier_init([self.kgs.entities_num, self.args.dim], 'ent_embeds', self.args.ent_l2_norm)
        self.rel_embeds = xavier_init([self.kgs.relations_num, self.args.dim], 'rel_embeds', self.args.rel_l2_norm)

def xavier_init(shape, name, is_l2_norm, dtype=None):
    with tf.name_scope('xavier_init'):
        embeddings = tf.get_variable(name, shape=shape, dtype=dtype, initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False))
    return tf.nn.l2_normalize(embeddings, 1) if is_l2_norm else embeddings
```

My manually load code:

```
ent_embed_np = np.load("npy/ent_embed_new_fromtf.npy")
rel_embed_np = np.load("npy/rel_embed_new_fromtf.npy")
mapping_mat_np = np.load("npy/mapping_mat_new_fromtf.npy")
    
def _define_variables(self):
    with tf.variable_scope('KG' + 'embeddings'):
        self.ent_embeds = tf.get_variable('ent_embeds', initializer=ent_embed_np, trainable=True)
        self.rel_embeds = tf.get_variable('rel_embeds', initializer=rel_embed_np, trainable=True)
```

The value of manually load embeds looks the same with the automatic initialized embeds, but the training process (including loss trend and evaluate metrics) is very different.

To compare different runs, I removed the randomness in the batch generation code, so the batch sequence is the same. When the program executes the first step of the first epoch, both the automatic and manual initialized embeds can calculate the same loss. The values of the embeddings are also the same before gradient descent.

The debugging process, shows the changed of embeds:

[`1st step auto`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14xvk.png)
[`1st step manual`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUqNz.png)
[`2nd step auto`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJvrz.png)
[`2nd step manual`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoGUT.png)

However, the optimizing result is different. In the second step, the loss of the automatically initialized embeddings decreases significantly, while the loss of the manually initialized embeddings decreases slowly.

This is a confusing point: why do the same loss, training parameters, and batch data lead to different optimization results? In the evaluation after 10 epochs, the hit values of the automatically optimized code are hits@[1,5,10] = [0.135 0.269 0.329], while the values of the manually initialized code are almost all 0. The loss of manually initialized embeds are higher than those of the automatically initialized.

[good result of automatic initialize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIZeR.png)

[bad result of manual initialize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffb5f.png)

What's the potential difference between 2 ways of initializing causing this problem?